# How can I capture site wide poll data to use later on

Tags: add-on

I have a client who wants what they call a 'Business Needs Survey Form' implemented into the site. The form will ask a series of around 30 business questions and once completed it will send off an email to sales team, and the user themself.

A subset of those 30 questions (Simple Needs Questions form (I did not come up with that name)) will be assigned to different areas of the site in order to entice the user to go and fill out the full Business Needs Survey.

The simple needs questions will have a simple yes or no answer option, which when chosen will reveal an answer that links off to one or more of the clients products or the full survey. **Those answers need to be progressively captured as the user flows through the site**.
With me so far? Cool. Here comes the question.

How is the best way to attack this?

My initial thinking was to:

1. Set up a channel to hold the questions and 2 different answers (one for yes one for no)
2. Use playa to allocate the questions to the different pages throughout the site
3. and possibly—this is where I'm stuck—capture the responses using safecracker to another channel which can then be pulled out when the user is ready.

NOTE: The user of the site will not be logged in, or have membership of any sorts.

Is this a good idea? 
Has anybody done anything like this before, or are there any addons out there that service this type of requirement?

*I'm really unsure on how to capture and store that data site wide.*

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers
Dan

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no out of the box or current third party addon that would provide the functionality requires. A custom addon needed to be developed.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might be able to use FreeForm here. It takes the submissions from a form and stores it in an an entry (although it's not shown in the regular Publish/Edit lists). You should be able to get the information out of the stored entries.

It also supports multi part forms, handles the emailing bits and provides a number of other features that you may find useful. There is a free and Pro version - the Pro version has the features such as multi part forms.

As for the logic involved in showing/hiding different fields I think you'll need to use javascript and come up with the flow yourself.

EDIT: removed incorrect information about channel storage - mixed up my add-ons!

Answer (score 3):

[ProForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/proform-drag-and-drop-form-builder) would support this pretty much out of the box. You could set each segment of questions as a step in the form, then use the simple form tag or a snippet to render the form. It will automatically render just the questions you ask for in that step.

If you do end up taking this route, I will provide full support for your design as I think this is really cool. You can post basically anything in the [support forum](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/proform-drag-and-drop-form-builder/viewforum/1840) and I will work with you until it works. :)

Comment: I need to be able to assign questions to different pages, as a prompt to fill out the full form, is that going to be possible?

Comment: Yes, with a little custom template code, you could do something like this fairly easily. Each step of the form can be processed on it's own.